# DjVu to PDFconverter

Tags: pdf, document-converter, djvu

I am looking for a program that:

- can convert a DjVu document to PDF
- is free
- doesn't come with crapware
- works off-line

If possible:

- run on Windows 7
- can convert severals DjVu documents to PDFs at once

I am aware of online converters and that we can view a DjVu then print as a PDF, but both solutions are a bit tedious.

Comment: There is a post [How to bulk convert .djvu files to .pdf?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262276/how-to-bulk-convert-djvu-files-to-pdf) at Ask Ubuntu. But I do not know whether some of the programs mentioned there have Windows ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DJView4](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/djview4.html) viewer has an option to export to PDF.

- it is free and open-source
- cross-platform
- no 64 bits version (I couldn't find it)
- runs offline
- compatible with Windows 7
- unfortunately only one PDF can be converted at once

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding also the information that the OCR layer is lost in the process. (At least with the version of djview I have tried. But I am unaware of *any* way to convert from djvu to pdf without loosing OCR layer.)

Comment: Unfortunately, DJview 4.11 that I tried also removes the outline from the djvu file during conversion. I wanted the outline to be there.